# Swift function that return -> String returns Optional string

Tags: swift, time

I have a function that calculates date:

```
func getFutureTime(_ timestamp: Double) -> String {
......
return "\(diffDateComponents.day) days"

}
```

I then call/set the funtion like:

```
futureTimeLabel.text = " \(Date().getFutureTime(timeStamp))"
```

But the time will show up as:

```
"Optional(4) days"
```

How can I saftley unwrap it so it doesnt print put as optional?

Comment: How are you printing the text? Is that how it shows up in the label or are you printing to the console?

Comment: Also I think they understand optionals from the title of the question.

Comment: I misread the text they were seeing, I thought it read "optional(4 days)", in which case it would've made a difference if they printed to the console like 'print(futureTimeLabel.text)' because the text property in a label is an optional. Also they understand that the difference between String and an Optional String otherwise they would not have become confused. They just missed the fact that the day property in diffDateComponents is also an optional.

Comment: Yeah fair, I totally understand the feeling of wanting to encourage people to educate themselves further. I just felt it wasn't contributing to the issue here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optional is here `diffDateComponents.day`.

If you're *really-really* sure that `day` property would be a value, you may use `diffDateComponents.day!`, like:

```
return "\(diffDateComponents.day!) days"
```

Otherwise you can use `??` operator to set default value:

```
return "\(diffDateComponents.day ?? defaultDaysCount) days"
```

Or, best solution:

```
if let days = diffDateComponents.day {
    return "\(days) days"
} else {
    return "Default message, when there're no days in future. The End is nigh, I guess…"
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. One should always mention safe unwrapping when answering a question about Optionals.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the functions return type, it is in this line:

```
return "\(diffDateComponents.day) days"
```

diffDateComponents.day is an optional Int so when you create the return string it interprets it like you are seeing.

unwrap the optional however you want as/before you create the return string to fix this problem. Eg

```
return "\(diffDateComponents.day!) days"
```